# WSO2 EI DataService with Grouped Input Parameter

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I'm using WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 6.5.0 's **DataService**,

I want to input **nested** parameters, 
i did not find any tutorials about that,
**it is my input :**

```
{
  "getBankCodes": {
    "SOURCE" : "12",
    "FUNCTION": "james",
    "REQUESTER" : "bond",
    "SECURITYCODE" : "bond@gmail.com"
  }
}
```

**Desired input is :**

```
{
  "source" : "123",
  "userId" : "test",
  "Request": {
    "SOURCE" : "12",
    "FUNCTION": "james",
    "REQUESTER" : "bond",
    "SECURITYCODE" : "bond@gmail.com"
  }
}
```

Source code :

```
  <query id="getBankCodes" useConfig="Datasource">
      <sql>Select BankCode, BankName From XAC_BANKCODES Where Substr(BankCode, Length(BankCode) - 3) = '0000'</sql>
      <result outputType="json">         &#xd;         &#xd;      { "Response":&#xd;      {"Banks":[&#xd;        {                   &#xd;         "Details": {&#xd;          "BankCode":"$BankCode",&#xd;          "BankName":"$BankName"&#xd;         }&#xd;        }                 &#xd;      ]&#xd;    }           &#xd;}</result>
      <param name="SOURCE" ordinal="1" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="FUNCTION" ordinal="1" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="REQUESTER" ordinal="1" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="SECURITYCODE" ordinal="1" sqlType="STRING"/>
   </query>
   <operation name="getBankCode">
      <call-query href="getBankCodes">
         <with-param name="SOURCE" query-param="SOURCE"/>
         <with-param name="FUNCTION" query-param="FUNCTION"/>
         <with-param name="REQUESTER" query-param="REQUESTER"/>
         <with-param name="SECURITYCODE" query-param="SECURITYCODE"/>
      </call-query>
   </operation>
   <resource method="POST" path="/getBankCodes">
      <call-query href="getBankCodes">
         <with-param name="SOURCE" query-param="SOURCE"/>
         <with-param name="FUNCTION" query-param="FUNCTION"/>
         <with-param name="REQUESTER" query-param="REQUESTER"/>
         <with-param name="SECURITYCODE" query-param="SECURITYCODE"/>
      </call-query>
   </resource>
```

**Please refer below questions**

- How to send grouped complex nested input parameters
- How to get input parameters as response(return What i sent as input) on this situation.

Regards,

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**How to send grouped complex nested input parameters**
Extracting the corresponding parameter is a mediation logic. Therefore, you have to write a proxy service/API in EI to extract inner param set from the request and call the dataservice.

**How to get input parameters as response(return What i sent as input) on this situation.**
You can do the same when you are writing a mediation logic.